# .htaccess help - rewriting completely

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been trying to fix this for a while now and it does not seem to work.

I currently have a `www.example.com/u?profile=Test` page which I instead want to have as a `www.example.com/u/Test` page for example.

I currently have...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

which removes the .php extension, no problems so far with that.

Any help is very much appreciated, although I hate asking for help like this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite `www.example.com/u/Test` to `www.example.com/u?profile=Test`   you can use :

```
RewriteEngine On
##remove php exten##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
##Rewrite "u/foo" to "u?profile=foo"##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ /u?profile=$1 [NC,L]
```